# How can i display records from one table where the number of outputed records depend on another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Vehicle

```
     +--------+--------+-----------+
     | regNo  |  make  |   model   |
     +------- +--------+-----------+
     | SM56ED |  BMW   | 3 Series  |
     +--------+--------+-----------+
     | GH45EM |  Audi  |    A3     |
     +--------+--------+-----------+
     | LM33ZG | Toyota |   Yaris   |
     +--------+--------+-----------+
     | ZR88HH | Suzuki |   Swift   |
     +--------+--------+-----------+
```

Booking

```
     +----+---------+------------+------------+
     | id |  regNo  | date_from  |  date_to   |
     +----+---------+------------+------------+
     | 1  | SM56ED  | 2015-03-20 | 2015-04-10 |
     +----+---------+------------+------------+
     | 2  | LM33ZG  | 2015-05-15 | 2015-05-22 |
     +----+---------+------------+------------+
```

So lets say i have these two tables. I want to check against two other dates, lets say:

```
    from: '2015-03-25' 
    to: '2015-04-05'
```

I want to display every car make, model which doesn't have a booking or the booking doesn't fall between the specified dates. So with the example above it should display the Audi, Toyota and Suzuki but not the BMW since there's a booking between the dates specified for that vehicle.

I have tried to use 'WHERE NOT EXISTS', inside checking if passed in dates fall 'BETWEEN' 'date_from' and 'date_to'. However this would either return all the vehicles if no vehicle is booked, or return 0 vehicles if at least one vehicle is booked between the dates.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to relate the query in the `not exists` part to the outer query (eg. make a correlated query):

```
select * from Vehicle v
where not exists (
    select 1 from Booking 
    where regNo = v.regNo
      and date_from <= '2015-04-05'
      and date_to   >= '2015-03-25' 
    )
```

A query built on the `exists` predicate is often the fastest solution.

Comment: I had a very similar solution (sadly deleted it already), and it didn't work, however this works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a db to test this out on ATM, but how about a join like so:

```
select * from Vehicle v left join Booking b on v.regNo = b.regNo where b.id is null or (b.date_from > '2015-03-25' and b.date_to < '2015-04-05')
```

Comment: This would exclude the Toyota too as there is an error in the query.

Comment: @Marius, sure. A normal join would exclude any Vehicle that didn't have a matching Booking, but a 'left' join means include all records on the left (Vehicle) no matter if a record is found on the right (Booking). Feel free to accept the answer if it helped. :)

Comment: @sqrfv But the query won't return the desired result?

Comment: @jpw, ah, yes, I flipped the dates. That's what I get for not testing in a db.